# Changing one parameter to 4 variables

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help me to improve this code? It isn't running in python 3.
Basically, I need to change `params` which is one parameter to include the 4 parameters.

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Users/Daniel/Downloads/mission01-template.py", line 25, in  show(mosaic(rcross_bb, sail_bb, corner_bb, nova_bb))
>   TypeError: mosaic() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

```
params=(rcross_bb, sail_bb, corner_bb, nova_bb)

def mosaic(params):
    return beside(stack(nova_bb,corner_bb),stack(rcross_bb,sail_bb))

show(mosaic(rcross_bb, sail_bb, corner_bb, nova_bb))
```

Comment: How many arguments did you pass to `mosaic`? The names in `params =` and `def mosaic(params)` have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Does it work if you change `def mosaic(params):` to `def mosaic(rcross_bb, sail_bb, corner_bb, nova_bb):`? You also might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help create a more reproducible example

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0):

The params defined outside the function and the formal parameters defined during the function definition are not connected. So according to the function, it has just a single argument, `params`